# What determines whether an UFO lands or gets intercepted?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

While early UFOs kept triggering interceptors, I've recently had a string of UFOs simply landing despite much better satellite coverage.

Is it random whether I get to try intercepting an UFO, or do I need to improve technology (e.g. get better interceptors) so that I get a chance of shooting them down?

Comment: Yeah, I think this might be a bug.  I've had the same UFO (UFO-0) land over and over again, even though I've got interceptors+sat coverage everywhere, and I always go to the site and kill the entire crew + salvage the UFO for parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to try intercepting a UFO if you have an interceptor assigned to the continent where the UFO is spotted (this assumes at least one deployed satellite, of course, or else you wouldn't spot the UFO).  To the best of my knowledge you always get a chance to intercept when these conditions are met.

Did you not have any interceptors assigned in the problem location, by chance?  Or is the UFO landing before the Interceptor can catch it?  If it's the latter, yes better tech can help (the Firestorm is much faster than the starting Interceptors).

As per comments on this answer some UFOs are just detected as landed (I don't recall having seen any but that doesn't mean much).  If so, I'm not sure there is anything you can do if satellite coverage on the continent is already maxed.  I haven't seen any detection upgrades (the Hyperwave Decoder has a completely different function in this game than in the original).  So, yeah, SOL.

Comment: Sometimes they just land even when you have satellites up and interceptors in range.

Comment: @Anna Lear - But you still get a chance to try and intercept based on my experience; granted the interceptor might not get to the UFO before it lands.

Comment: Nope. It just says that a landed UFO was detected and your only option is to dispatch the Skyranger.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this is incorrect. Intercepting UFOs and assaulting landed UFOs are unrelated occurences.

Comment: @Kotekzot - changed my answer before you commented, FWIW.

Comment: @AnnaLear: yes, that's exactly what's happening to me.